# how to make implode create <br /> automatic after displaying 5 things in a row?

Tags: php

I want to make implode to display only 5 arrays after that it automatic creates a new row displaying 5 arrays again and it keep repeating itself. like is it possible to use  `<br />` or something else I had to use to do that?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `im_album` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  ");
$types = array();
$d_array = array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $types[] = $row['name'];
    $d_array[] = $row['description'];
}
echo "<h1>".implode($types )."</h1>"
```

Comment: i think if you have got the array than why not try like for($i=1;$i<count($your_array);$i++){ display the array if($i/5==0)(echo"<br/>");}

Comment: alright i would display it hold

Comment: I never done this before, to break it after a sudden length

Comment: check this .length was a typo

Comment: Please add the output of `print_r($types);` & your desired output.

Comment: is their a way to use that in implode because to be honest i dont understand whats going on their, can you show me by using this code if its possible `echo "<h1>".implode($types )."</h1>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `im_album` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  ");
$types = array();
$d_array = array();
$types_str="";
$types_str_array=array();
$temp=1;
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {

    $types_str .=$row['name'];

    if($temp!=1 && $temp%5==0)
    {
        $types_str_array[]=$types_str;
        $types_str="";
    }

    $types[] = $row['name'];
    $d_array[] = $row['description'];

    $temp++;
}
echo "<h1>".implode("<br />",$types_str_array )."</h1>";
```

Comment: it works thanks for your help :),, ima mess around with the script so i could understand it

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php

//sample array
$types = array("John", "Doe", "Bar", "Baz", "Stock", "Overflow", "Meta" );

//Count the number of elements in $types
$types_count = count($types);

//Use $foo1, $foo2, $foo3 as the output array names
$out_types_count = 1;
$out_types_arr = "foo".$out_types_count;


for($i=1;$i<=$types_count;$i++){
    $out_types_arr[] = $types[$i];
    if(($i%5) == 0){ // if we $i == 5,10,15 etc, 
        $out_types_count++; // use $foo2
        $out_types_arr = "foo".$out_types_count;
    }
}// for loop ENDS

//Echo all the output    
for($i=1;$i<=$out_types_count;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<=5;$j++){
        echo $out_types_arr.$i[$j];
    }
    echo "<br />".PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

P.S. Code has some errors & minor not-desired output. Because OP has got the answer he wanted, so I am gonna correct it later, from home.

Comment: i still dont get this, never done this before. so than how do i display should i use implode or echo?